# Android Application cannot open socket to connect Server

Tags: android, sockets, client

I am developing an Android Application, and application needs to connect server.
This is the client code. 79.123.176.59 is the server's IP address. Application and the server are connected to same network. When I execute my application, it never opens a socket. So it cannot connect to server.

When I execute client code seperate from the application, it just works fine!

What is the problem ? Do you have any suggestions ?

Thank you!

```
int port=8080;
   Socket s;
   String msg="";
   String err="error";
   try{
       Log.d("Client","Socket");
       s=new Socket("79.123.176.59",port);
       Log.d("Client","Socket opened");
       OutputStreamWriter osw=new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream());
       PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(osw);
       BufferedReader br1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
       Log.d("Client","Streams");
       pw.println(latitude + " " + longitude );
       Log.d("Client","String send");
       pw.flush();
       msg=br1.readLine();
       return msg;
   }
   catch ( Exception e )
   {
       return err;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing the socket neither the streams. So maybe you cannot connect because your device is blocked by a socket you opened before.
Try to put this after your catch (and dont do return inside try/catch)

```
finally {

        pw.close();
        br1.close();
        s.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[TCP SOCKET on Android](http://www.anddev.org/general-f3/socket-programming-t325.html) You can follow this thread and the code is also available there.

Answer (score 0):

The `Socket` constructor does not take a string, I don't get how that even compiles?

Try this

```
s=new Socket(new InetAddress.getByName("79.123.176.59"),port)
```

Comment: Check it please. new InetAddress.getByName("79.123.176.59") is wrong because getByName is static method
s=new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("79.123.176.59"),port)